# Alternative ways for displaying a web page in Qt

Tags: google-maps, qwebview, qwebkit

When I visit [this webpage](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple), which is a simple map from Google Maps with, for example, Chrome or Firefox, everything is natural. You can double click to zoom in, you can drag the map and you can drag the street view mode icon.

But when this web page is loaded into a QWebView object with the following code, I don't have mouse dragging ability. So for example I can't drag the map to change it.

```
QWebView view;
view.setUrl(QUrl("https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple"));
view.show();
```

And I couldn't find any solution for it so far. Is there any other way to display a web page in a Qt widget?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a sample browser in Qt that provides this functionality:

> [QTDIR]\demos\browser

I'm not sure how long this has been included, but it's certainly in 4.8. It implements a fairly complete browser but the code you're interested in is in the file webview.cpp. This wraps QWebView and demonstrates how to implement mouse events, clicks, downloads, etc.

Answer (score 0):

QtWebkit is kind of Buggy and uses a very old version of rendering Engine .which could only be compared to early versions of chrome or safari .
If you are just planning to give a simple preview of the webpage inside the application you could use QWebEngine.

it will give you better rendering (refer this link)

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebEngineHowToTry

the project is still under Development .and many features like js injection etc are still missing .

Know this fact Webpage rendering is a mess in Qt.

(if nothing works for you can completely drop Qt and try Mozilla XUL ,it has a very good webpage layout engine "Gecko")